# Move large file (500GB or more) between s3 buckets without a Server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a small Python script that runs a Lambda job to moves files from a un-restricted s3 bucket to a restricted s3 bucket as soon as those files have been uploaded. The original goal was for a 50GB file, this is now a 500GB file (or larger) target. The Lambda container stops at 15 minutes, and I'm only able to transfer about 100GB before the end of the Lambda timeout.

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')  #for s3 delete function
... other stuff ...
s3_resource.meta.client.copy(Bucket=target_bucket, Key=key, CopySource=copy_source, ExtraArgs={'ServerSideEncryption':'AES256'})
#boto3 manual states s3_resource.meta.client.copy "is a managed transfer which will perform a multipart copy in multiple threads if necessary."
```

I've looked around and I the options I found would be to:

1. Use ECS container to run the jobs, triggered by s3 event and lambda
2. Use Step Functions to generate a loop for a multipart uploads that will last longer then 15 minutes

I haven't worked with ether service yet. What are some of the pros/cons of ECS vs Step Function? Are their other ways to (code or settings) that I can adjust to get the file transfer limit higher.

**UPDATE 1**
System details.

The "public" bucket is used with a SFTP service. This is replacing a SFTP server on a Linux box. 
When a File is sent to me the Lambda checked where internally it needed to be placed.
When I make a file available to download, the lambda for directory where that file is places and places it in the correct SFTP directory. Bucket policies archive file after a given window, which doesn't allow them to be downloaded unless needed again.
The goal is that files sent to me will not remain on a public/SFTP exposed bucket. When files are posted for download they are only there for a set period of time.  While my internal buckets retain and use files.
Even with the layer of SFTP access control I would prefer to have the external exposed bucket to be mostly empty.

**UPDATE 1** 
Step Function multipart upload example found

I found an example with some code snips of multi-part upload (sequential [a, then b, then c...] and parallel parts [a, b, and c, and then ...] ). It does look like a lot of session ID management. Differently not something I would want to trouble shoot in 6 months after not looking at it in a long time.

Comment: Is it an option to you use scp?

Comment: @Danizavtz  scp = secure copy linux command? I'm trying to do this server-less. I can move these large files fine when I have a machine that doesn't time out after 15 minutes.  scp = aws Secure Control Policies?  If your thinking avoid the move by just addressing object permissions, the move job has some logic  that helps organize files after uploads.

Comment: I mean linux command.

Comment: I was thinking in easy solutions, maybe do some tar.gz before copy. If the file size become around 100GB maybe you can do the work without big changes in code.

Comment: S3 replication is the best solution here if you can use it. You won't even need your Lambda function anymore. The suggestions about `scp` makes no sense in relation to S3. If you have to build it yourself I would use S3 notifications -> SQS queue -> ECS task on Fargate that is auto-scaled based on the depth of the queue. I don't see how the Step Functions thing would even work, coordinating multipart uploads across multiple Lambda instances seems very error prone if it's even possible.

Comment: @RunThor Can you tell us more about your actual use-case? For example, why do you need to do the copy? Is it because a user might upload a file with the same name as an existing object, and you don't want it overwritten? How are users uploading the files? You can separate the permission to upload from the permission to view/download objects.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I've updated  the original post with some system details.

Comment: It's been a year since the original post, considering I've had this discussion elsewhere, here is what I found, ranked with how much I like them.
1. S3 replication is by far the fastest solution, especially across regions. Rules/functions can take a bit of getting use to. Triggering actions post replication can be tricky, but not impossible.
2. EC2/ECS usually with autoscaling and SQS for "job management". Allows for more after-action flexibility. Have seen it be ~3x slower then replication for larger files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use S3 Replication function. That will allow you to replica the info in the first S3 and replicate it in different AWS Regions (cross-Region replication) or you can replicate objects across buckets in the same AWS Region.
This function is available a the S3 as show in the image below.

Now, the 15 minutes limit in Lambda is a hard limit. Moreover, if your code last more than 15 minutes then lambda is not an adequate solution.

[image: S3 Console]

Comment: Interesting solution. I'll take a look at this it may work. There is some more logic in that script, which I didn't include, but I maybe able to use this to help with the big lift of moving files between buckets.

Comment: Good luck! If you need something more advanced, probably you will need to use a EC2 or StepFunctions.

Comment: Using replication is a good idea. Some things to consider: You'll need a way to delete the original object _after_ the copy has been performed. Replication requires Versioning to be turned on, so you'll need to intentionally delete the **correct version of the source object** rather than the object itself. Also note that Versioning will need to be turned on in the _destination_ bucket too, which might complicate things being done there. Perhaps trigger the deletion via an AWS Lambda function on the _destination_ bucket, which goes back and deletes the object in the _source_ bucket?

Comment: I reviewed the design needs and found that S3 Replication was indeed the cleanest way to get 90% there. A much more simple solution took care of the last 10%.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution would be to use an Amazon EC2 instance instead of an AWS Lambda function.

If you are okay to have the files sitting in the first bucket for a while, then you could simply run the instance on a regular schedule (eg twice a day). If you need it to work more quickly, you could have a **Lambda function that launches an EC2 instance when a new file appears**.

An Amazon EC2 instance is actually quite low-cost. A `t2.nano` instance is only `$0.0058 per Hour` and you are only charged per second.

The flow would be:

- **Amazon S3 Event** is triggered when new object is created, which runs an AWS Lambda function
- The **AWS Lambda function** starts an existing Amazon EC2 instance
- The **EC2 instance** has a script in `/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/` that is automatically executed on every startup (not just the first boot):

```
aws s3 mv --recursive . s3://target-bucket/
aws s3 mv --recursive . s3://target-bucket/
sudo shutdown now -h
```

This will move the files to a target bucket, which means the files are copied and then deleted. If multiple files are uploaded close to each other, nothing will go wrong because the Lambda function will simply try to start an instance that is already started. The `mv` line is intentionally duplicated so that it runs again in case more files were uploaded during the copy period. (It could be written smarter to check for files and keep looping.)

While a `t2.nano` instance has limited network bandwidth, it should be sufficient to copy large objects because it is simply sending `CopyPart()` messages to S3, rather than transferring the data itself.

Comment: I'm up-voting this solution, may mark as the solution later.  This would allow me to convert much of the logic I have built already. I think I'll also be able to use both S3 event triggers and cloudwatch cron triggers to make sure nothing goes sitting for too long (belt+suspenders). This solution is simple and nearly-serverless. I do have a few other tasks where Fargate/ECS maybe needed so I may rebuild this again there as a training/learning project. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can certainly use Fargate instead of an EC2 instance.